# early return from a void-func in Swift?

Tags: swift

Can someone explain me the following behaviour in Swift?

```
func test() -> Bool {
    print("1 before return")
    return false
    print("1 after return")
}


func test2() {
    print("2 before return")
    return
    print("2 after return")
}


test()
test2()
```

returns:

```
1 before return
2 before return
2 after return
```

I would expect that `print("2 after return")` would never be executed since it is after a `return` statement.

Is there something I am missing?

(tested with Swift 4 / 4.1 & Xcode 9.2 / Xcode 9.3 beta 2)

Comment: Hm, that's really weird. If I add a semicolon efter return in test2, "2 after return" isn't printed, however. But as you say, it shouldn't be printed at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a tricky thing, Swift doesn't require semi-colons (they are optionally used), this makes Swift compiler automatically deduce whether is the next line should be a new line, or a completion for the old one. `print()` is a function that returns void. So the word `return print("something")`, is valid. So

```
return
print("Something")
```

could be deduced as `return print("Something")`

Your solution is to write

```
return;
print("Something")
```

Comment: Yes, it contains them, you could use a semi-colon if you want, for example:  you want to put two statements on the same line use `print("This is first"); print("This is second")`. But the semi-colon is optional, doesn't make compilation errors

Answer (score 4):

`func test2()` is similar to `func test2() -> Void`

So your code gets treated as,

```
func test2() -> Void {
  print("2 before return")
  return print("2 after return")
}
```

Adding semicolon after print should fix it.

```
func test2() -> Void {
  print("2 before return")
  return; print("2 after return")
}
```

You can also see the error if you place value type after return line and you will understand more,

```
func test2() {
  print("2 before return")
  return
  2
}
```

> error: unexpected non-void return value in void function   2   ^

Answer (score 3):

When I tried this in the IBM Swift Sandbox I got the following warning:

> ```
> warning: expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'
>     print("2 after return")
>     ^
> ```

which pretty much explains the issue.  Swift is interpreting it as if you had written:

```
return(print("2 after return"))
```

The print statement is executed and the return value of the print `()` is returned.

Adding `;` after the return makes that a separate statement

```
return;
print("2 after return")
```

and then the warning becomes:

> ```
> warning: code after 'return' will never be executed
>     print("2 after return")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
func noReturn() {...}
```

is the same as

```
func noReturn() -> (Void) {...} //or func noReturn() -> ()
```

and since print(...) has the same signature it is ok to call 
    return print(...)
in a void function

Answer (score 0):

Answer extracted from question:

**It seems the problem is, that swift does not exit the function instantly on a return statement in a void function *and* uses the consecutive `void` value as the function parameter and terminates as expected if it is non-void.**

> Code after 'return' will never be executed

```
[...]
return; // <- would return here

[...]
return () // <- would return here

[...]
return // <- would return here
let x = 42
```

**If Xcode would work reliably this message should be shown on the next examples:**

> Expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'

```
[...]
return
print("oh no") // <- would return here

[...]
return
myClosure("this feels wrong") // <- would return here and execute the function / closure
```

> This issue is already in the Swift-bug-tracker since 2016:
>   https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2028