# Xcode 10.1 "return" statement doesn't stop function execution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, return, xcode10.1

The `return` statement in Xcode 10.1 is not honoured by debugger,

For eg.,

```
    func doSomething() {

        print("Task A")
        return

        print("Task B")
    }
```

This prints

```
Task A
Task B //This is not expected to be printed as we have a `return` before this line
```

Can someone help me!

Comment: That should not happen. Try a clean and rebuild. Sometimes Xcode loses its mind and does not rebuild your source files after you make changes.

Comment: @DuncanC: It *does* happen (see the linked-to Q&A). Swift executes the statement `return print("Task B")`, which prints the string and returns void. – Whether that should be considered a bug or not is a different story. Inserting a semicolon helps.

Comment: @MartinR, well it's definitely not a bug, just a natural quirk of non-mandatory-semicolon syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because expression after `return` is treated as argument of `return`.
So your code understood by compiler as:

```swift
func doSomething() {
    print("Task A")
    return print("Task B")
}
```

To prevent it you can use semicolon to explicitly separate this expressions.
Like that:

```swift
func doSomething() {
    print("Task A")
    return;
    print("Task B")
}
```

Comment: ... as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/48887696/1187415 :)

Comment: @MartinR yeah, I failed to find this question :D